# Azure login using Javascript in zabbix server. its using duktape javascript implementation

Tags: javascript, zabbix, duktape

i need to login to Azure from Zabbix server that is located in Azure
i enabled identity on the server
now i need to login to azure using the identity within a javascript item
i saw that in need to import @Azure/Identity
but i dont know how
i am infrastructure man with low knowledge of JavaScript

I installed npm on the server
then

`npm install @azure/identity`

and then tried this example script that i never got it to work
Duktape engin apparently doesnt accept the following

`const { BlobServiceClient } = require('@azure/storage-blob');`

it should be

`var BlobServiceClient = require('azure/storage-blob');`

the full example script is this:

```
// connect-with-default-azure-credential.js
const { BlobServiceClient } = require('@azure/storage-blob');
const { DefaultAzureCredential } = require('@azure/identity');
require('dotenv').config()

const accountName = process.env.AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME;
if (!accountName) throw Error('Azure Storage accountName not found');

const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(
  "https://${accountName}.blob.core.windows.net",
  new DefaultAzureCredential()
);
```

Comment: of course it doesnt work, look into the code at https://git.zabbix.com/projects/ZBX/repos/zabbix/browse/templates/cloud/azure_http to see a working example of interacting with the Azure API

Comment: I saw indeed that i can interact with azure using service principal. And am using it.  But it needs a secret. And i dont want that. I want to use machine identity. Its possible using that module am trying to import in zabbix script

Comment: no because you cannot import that module into Duktape, and Duktape modules need recompile see https://github.com/svaarala/duktape/blob/master/extras/module-duktape/README.rst

Comment: Thank you Iron Bishop.
i still need to search how to compile it and how to get it into zabbix system
but thanks for the helpful information